# Is there a bash command for converting an entire directory to HAML from HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, haml, html2haml

I'm looking to convert an entire directory of HTML to HAML so that the files have the same name but with a new extension.

```
html2haml file.html.erb file.haml
```

Can I run a loop so that I can convert all these files all at once so that the name is the same just the extension is changed?

My files:

```
continue_login.html.erb
expired_trial.html.erb
expired_trial.mobile.erb
login.html.erb
login.mobile.erb
recover_password.html.erb
signup.html.erb
trial_expires_soon.html.erb
trial_expires_soon.mobile.erb
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not sexy but it's working:

```
for file in $(find . -type f -name \*.html.erb); do
  html2haml -e ${file} "$(dirname ${file})/$(basename ${file} .erb).haml";
done
```

(Pay attention to the `-e` flag of `html2haml` it parses the ERb tags.)

Comment: Throw this in there `for f in *.html.erb; do rm $f; done` And you can clean up the old *.html.erb files

Comment: Just to add, backticks fork a new process, so it's better practice to use `$(...)`

Comment: What do you mean by `$(...)`?

Comment: tadman: replace the first (left side) backtick with `$(` and the second (right side) one with `)`

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
for f in *.html.erb; do html2haml $f ${f/\.html\.erb/.haml}; done
```

Edit: If you need to look for template files recursively and you're using `bash` 4.x, then you can use [`globstar`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html):

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.html.erb; do html2haml $f ${f/\.html\.erb/.haml}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://gist.github.com/pho3nixf1re/1281382 looks like it does a whole directory tree:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  wdir="."
else
  wdir=$1
fi

for f in $( find . -name '*.erb' ); do
  out="${f%.erb}.haml"
  if [ -e $out ]; then
    echo "skipping $out; already exists"
    # rm $f
  else
    echo "hamlifying $f"
    html2haml $f > $out
    # rm $f
  fi
done
```